# What is the best way to search for a value in a list of list of strings?

Tags: python

I have the following lists of stings (series):

```
serie_1 = ['ABC1', 'ABC2', 'AFG9']
serie_2 = ['CX1', 'CX9', 'CXL']
serie_3 = ['HOM1', 'HOM65']
```

I have a string (as an input) and I want to check to which list it belongs to so that I output a different value. For example, if INPUT = 'HOM112343', then I need to output (log) "Alpha serie", if INPUT = 'HOM65XL' then I need to output "Home Design".

I have this and it's working fine:

```
if any(ser in INPUT.upper() for ser in serie_1):
    return "Alpha serie"
if any(ser in INPUT.upper() for ser in serie_2):
    return "Casio Extreme"
if any(ser in INPUT.upper() for ser in serie_3):
    return "Home Design"
```

I'm wondering what's the best approach to do this, and if there's an alternative more efficient way to do it as my series (serie_4, _5, _6 ...) are getting bigger overtime.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is a match? Does the input value have to start with the value in your series? What, if one series contains "CX" and another one contains "CX1"?

Comment: By which logic, would INPUT = 'HOM112343' lead to output "Alpha serie"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use separate variables for the lists, put them in a dictionary. Then you can loop through the dictionary, and return the key when you find a match.

```
serie = {
    "Alpha serie": ['ABC1', 'ABC2', 'AFG9'],
    "Casio Extreme": ['CX1', 'CX9', 'CXL'],
    "Home Design": ['HOM1', 'HOM65']
}

INPUT = INPUT.upper()

for key, values in serie.items():
    if any(ser in INPUT for ser in values):
        return key
```

Comment: I actually meant to do that, that's the whole reason I reassigned the variable :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, creating a reverse lookup dictionary where each value of a series is mapped against the name of the series:

```
seriesdata = {'Alpha serie': {'ABC1', 'ABC2', 'AFG9'},
              'Casio Extreme': {'CX1', 'CX9', 'CXL'},
              'Home Design': {'HOM1', 'HOM65'},
             }
lookupdict = {}
for series, vals in seriesdata.items():
    lookupdict.update({v: series for v in vals})
```

For the lookup-function, first do the lookup with the whole string and if no answer is found, cut off the last character until a result is found:

```
def lookup(inp):
    inp = inp.upper()
    while inp:
        if inp in lookupdict:
            return lookupdict[inp]
        inp = inp[:-2]
    return None
```

Whether or not this is more efficient than iterating over the elements, depends on your data, how many series, how many entries per series and how many extra characters in your input string.

```
>>> lookup('HOM65XL')
'Home Design'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a dictionary with all the series values to map them directly to the corresponding name.

```
serie_1 = ['ABC1', 'ABC2', 'AFG9']
serie_2 = ['CX1', 'CX9', 'CXL']
serie_3 = ['HOM1', 'HOM65']

series = (series_1,series_2,series_3)
names  = ("Alpha serie","Casio Extreme","Hoe Design")

groups = { m:n for s,n in zip(series,names) for m in s }
```

Then your function would only need a single line to return the name corresponding to the input:

```
return groups[INPUT.upper()]
```